# How to refresh arrows on bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I wrote a code that displays google map with markers and arrows between the markers using bokeh.
Upon selecting/deselecting items - the markers on the map are refreshing (some disappear, other re-appear).
The refreshing code of the markers:

```
 photo_filter = BooleanFilter(booleans=[True] * len(df)) # Starts with all TRUE filter, i.e. all photos shown
    checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=unique_people, active=[idx for idx in range(len(unique_people))]) # Creates the Checkboxes for the people
    checkboxes.js_on_change('active',
                            CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, f=photo_filter),
                                     code="""\
                                 const checked_boxes = cb_obj.active.map(idx => cb_obj.labels[idx]);
                                 f.booleans = source.data.people.map(list => list.some(item => checked_boxes.includes(item)));
                                 source.change.emit();
                             """)) # Responsible for refreshing and updating the page every time something is changed in Checkboxes
```

I could not find how to refresh the arrows - so that they will re-display based on the now-appearing markers.

I am drawing the arrows using this code:

```
arrows = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(X_start=X_start, Y_start=Y_start, X_end=X_end, Y_end=Y_end))
map.add_layout(Arrow(end=OpenHead(line_color="blue", line_width=2, size=12),
                    x_start='X_start', y_start='Y_start', x_end='X_end', y_end='Y_end', source=arrows))
```

Can someone help?